# Examining sequence convergence with parameter $a$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

For $a\in R$, let $x_1=a$ and $x_{n+1}$=$-\frac{6x_n^2+4x_n}{x_n^2-2x_n+4}$. Examine the convergence of the sequence ${(x_n)}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ for different values of $a$. Also find $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$ whenever it exist.

I know that if the sequence converges to $x$ then it must satisfy $x$=$-\frac{6x^2+4x}{x^2-2x+4}$, that is $x=0$. 
$x_{n+1}$$-$$x_n$=-$\frac{x_n(x_n^2+4x_n+8)}{x_n^2-2x_n+4}$ and should use it to find out whether the sequence is monotone . But i don't know how to do it and how to use $a$ in all this and find $a$ so that the sequence converges. Can someone explain it ? Thanks.

I can't find any answer. I'm stuck. If someone can help ,please do it:)

Comment: The sequence is not monotonic Here is some examples for $a=0.5$ we have $$\{0.5,-1.07692,-0.36246,0.136231,-0.175189,0.117919,-0.146928,0.106173,-0.129597,0.0976652\}$$ for $a=21$ this happens $$\{21.,-6.77419,-3.91313,-2.80863,-2.06196,-1.39486,-0.697663,-0.0220583,0.0210932,-0.0219901\}$$ and this for $a=-3$ $$\{-3.,-2.21053,-1.53872,-0.852405,-0.147704,0.106531,-0.130116,0.0979347,-0.117808,0.0912953\}$$

Comment: So does that mean that the sequence converge only if $a$$=$$0$  and $x_n$$=$$0$ ?

Comment: No, no! It DOES converge to zero, but it's not monotonic. It is not alternating either.

Comment: The sequence is not defined for $x_1 = 2$.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible real limit is
$0$,
since all the other roots of
$x
=-\frac{6x^2+4x}{x^2-2x+4}
$
are complex.

Around zero,
it can't be monotone
since
$x_{n+1}
=-\frac{x_n(6x_n+4)}{x_n^2-2x_n+4}
$
has the opposite sign
of $x_n$.

What is needed,
imho,
is to write
$x_{n+2} = \text{some function}(x_n)$.
This would probably show convergence,
but I'm too lazy right now
to do it.

Comment: I think i got it, but if you could do it when you can I'll be so grateful. Thanks you so much